# Remove String Literals from Python Strings when writing a File

Tags: python, string

I am writing some text to file in Python. The problem is that the string literals with extra singles quotes get written to the file. I want to avoid that.

I have a multiple language string which i first encode using

```
 my_string = str('other language string').encode('utf-8')
 file.open('my_file.txt', 'w', newline = '')
 file.write(my_string)
```

It saves the following output to the file

```
b'other language string'
```

I want the output to be only

```
other language string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've opened the file in text mode, which will encode data *for* you. Just write the string directly *without* encoding:

```
file.write('other language string')
```

The default encoding for text files is UTF-8, but you can give the `open()` call a different encoding if you so wish.

Alternatively, open the file in *binary* mode with `'wb'` instead of `'w'`, encode manually like you did and write byte objects.

Comment: Thanks! I am using the newline so it does not allow me to use the binary mode. Updated the question for opening code.

Comment: @backTangent: Then don't encode, there is no need to as Python 3 takes care of that *for you*.